How to Handle Indexes for @MapsId in JPA: Should FK and PK Share the Same Index?
I am using the @MapsId annotation in JPA to map a foreign key (FK) to a primary key (PK). According to the @MapsId annotation, the FK and PK share the same value. However, when I checked the database schema, I noticed that the index is created only for the PK.
Example:
@Entity(name = "PostDetails")
@Table(name = "post_details")
public class PostDetails {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId
    private Post post;
}

My Questions:
Indexing FK and PK: Since id is both the PK and the FK in this case, shouldn't there be a single shared index that serves as both the PK and FK index?
Unnecessary Indexes: Since the FK and PK are the same, is it necessary to add an additional index for the FK, or would that be redundant?
Best Practices: What are the best practices for handling indexes in this scenario to ensure optimal performance without redundancy?
Additional Information:
Database: I am using MsSQL, MySQL, Oracle.
Observation: Currently, the index is created only for the PK, and there is no separate index explicitly for the FK in the database schema. Since PK and FK are the same, I do not want to add an extra unnecessary index for FK. What would be the most optimal solution for this?
Any insights or recommendations on how to handle this situation would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.
https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Since you are using 3 different brands of RDBMS, there may be 3 different answers!  Suggest you post 3 separate Questions.

Also, provide the generated SQL for creating the table and for SELECTing.

By ID being both a PK and FK, I assume you mean that you have another supertype table where ID is also the PK, and the table in question is a subtype sharing the same key. If that's the case, your FK constrains the subtype to use IDs that exist in the supertype.
I can answer your question only as it relates to Oracle:
Unlike a PK or UK, an FK is not an index - it's a rule preventing inserts/updates on the table if the ID being inserted isn't in the parent/supertype table. There's no index (necessarily) involved in an FK on the child table. The parent table requires an index (a unique index defined explicitly as a constraint, in fact, usually the PK, but could be a UK). But the child table where the FK constraint is defined does not. Now, it's usually a very good practice to add an index on a column with an FK, because that will speed up deletes on the parent table (which have to check the child tables for any orphaned values before the delete is allowed, and this is immensely helped by an index), but it's not required, and won't be automatically created just because you defined an FK.
In your case, however, ID is already indexed by virtue of being your PK. You have no need to further index it. In fact, Oracle will not permit you to, as it does not allow two indexes with the same set of columns on the same table. One index is all you need in this scenario, and all you will be permitted to have.

Paul, thanks for the detailed explanation. Just to clarify, querying by PK (id) and FK (post.id) in my PostDetails table should have the same performance, right? Since id is indexed as the PK, this should optimize both types of queries. Vlad Mihalcea mentions that sharing the PK can reduce the index footprint by half, enhancing memory usage and index scanning speed. Any additional considerations for performance? https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

@YusufBESTAS, I'm afraid I can only speak to Oracle. I'm not sure what you mean by post.id. Column names don't have a dot in them. How is post.id different than id ? To get help on performance questions, you'll need to use Oracle's language and DDL, not abstract it through your client framework.
